# self made Neural Network does not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

So I tried to write my own neural network in Python (without using any libraries except of numpy and random for the exp function and random for the learn function), I can't figure out why it is not learning as it should... Please help me fix it so it will work.
I think the problem is in  the backpropagation function/ the weight changing function, does anyone see any thing wrong with the calculations?

```
def changeWeights(self):
    i = 0
    while i < self.layersAmount:
        j = 0
        while j < self.layers[i].amountOfNuerons:
            k = 0
            while k < len(self.layers[i].neurons[j].weights):
                weight = self.layers[i].neurons[j].weights[k]
                err = self.layers[i].neurons[j].error
                ans = self.layers[i].neurons[j].ans
                gradient = err * sigmoid_derivative(ans) * LEARNING_RATE
                self.layers[i].neurons[j].weights[k] += gradient * ans
                self.layers[i].neurons[j].bias += gradient
                k += 1
            j += 1
        i += 1

def backprop(self, errors):
    i = len(self.layers) - 1
    for j in range(self.outputs):   
        self.layers[i].neurons[j].error = errors[j]
    i -= 1
    while i > -1:
        k = 0
        while k < len(self.layers[i].neurons):
            sum = 0
            for j in range(len(self.layers[i + 1].neurons)):
                weight = self.layers[i + 1].neurons[j].weights[k]
                sum += weight * self.layers[i + 1].neurons[j].error
            self.layers[i].neurons[k].error = sum
            k += 1
        i -= 1
    self.changeWeights()
```

Comment: I guess you can't expect that someone looks through all the code for your neural network. That is usually complex and there are many many examples available online, e.g. https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-3rd-edition/blob/master/ch02/ch02.py

Comment: Please try to narrow your problem down to one very specific thing. Then try to post a very short example, say 10 to 20 lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @BenAkhovan Which part is not working? You want to have test procedures for every independent function to make sure they work as expected.